# batch file to search for file and list the directory

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch file that automatically starts a program, and if the program is not in the original location, it pops up a window, and asks the user to search for the file themselves.  this is done with a batch to exe program, and it even includes some advanced commands.   the one I used was:

```
rem browsefolder
```

you can get the compiler here: http://www.battoexeconverter.com/  anyway, if the user can't find the file, I would like to have an autosearch function available.  It would have to chech all directories, and might take a while.  I would also need the command to store the location of the file, once it has been found, as a variable.  I can't just automatically start it, because I need to kill other processes first, and It would just be alot better to have it as a variable.  I have no idea if this is possible, so I'm sorry if this is an outragious request.  Once again, I only need the search function.  The rest I already have completed.

Comment: Try AutoHotkey... Dont down vote.. This cleary about having the program not how

Comment: Try using [PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd835506(v=vs.85).aspx) and calling it from cmd. Or, better yet, just rewrite the thing in PowerShell.

Comment: Should be possible.  How do you suggest handling multiple files with the same name? meaning - how will the user know which one to pick?

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

:: the file to look for. (In this case 'myFile.txt')
set filename=myFile.txt

:: the drive or path to search. (In this case searching current drive)
set searchPath=\

:: If the file is found. This variable will be set
set foundFilePath=

:: echos all found paths and returns the last occurrance of the file path
FOR /R "%searchPath%" %%a  in (%filename%) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~fa" (
        echo "%%~fa" 
        SET foundFilePath=%%~fa
    )
)

IF EXIST "%foundFilePath%" (
    echo The foundFilePath var is set to '%foundFilePath%'
) else (
    echo Could not find file '%filename%' under '%searchPath%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will search the current drive for `file.exe` and set the variable to the location of the last match in the drive.

```
@echo off
for /r \ %%a in (file.exe) do set "location=%%~dpa"
```